# I am confused by this question on operational amplifiers though my issue relates to voltage dividing

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, voltage-divider

[image: Op Amp circuit with impedances.]

The op-amp is ideal.

I performed the analysis and ended up with:

$$Av = \frac{Z1(Z3+Z4)}{Z4(Z1+Z2)}$$

This being calculated by working out V+ and V-.

I believed that

\$V+ = Vin\frac{Z1}{Z1+Z2}\$ and

\$V- = Vout\frac{Z4}{Z3+Z4}\$

I am a little confused why this isn't the case.

Comment: Your V+ and V– equations are wrong. Revise resistive voltage dividers.

Comment: Realised my error, was using the voltage divider eqn wrong. Voltage at point V- and V+ is what voltage is "left" after dropping it over Z4 and Z1 respectively. ( what no sleep does to a mans brain :(  )

Comment: Ask yourself what will happen for Z2 approaching infinity?

Answer (score 0):

Well, first notice that the current flowing through \$\displaystyle\text{Z}_4\$ is th same current that is flowing through \$\displaystyle\text{Z}_3\$. So, we can write:

$$\text{I}_{\text{Z}_4}=\text{I}_{\text{Z}_3}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{out}-\text{V}_-}{\displaystyle\text{Z}_4}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_--0}{\displaystyle\text{Z}_3}\tag1$$

And for \$\displaystyle\text{Z}_1\$ and \$\displaystyle\text{Z}_2\$ we have the same:

$$\text{I}_{\text{Z}_1}=\text{I}_{\text{Z}_2}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{in}-\text{V}_+}{\displaystyle\text{Z}_1}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_+-0}{\displaystyle\text{Z}_2}\tag2$$

Now, we know that for an ideal opamp we have:

$$\text{V}_-=\text{V}_+:=\text{V}\tag3$$

So, we get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{out}-\text{V}}{\displaystyle\text{Z}_4}&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}-0}{\displaystyle\text{Z}_3}\\
\\
\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{in}-\text{V}}{\displaystyle\text{Z}_1}&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}-0}{\displaystyle\text{Z}_2}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\mathscr{H}:=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{out}}{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{in}}=\frac{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}\text{Z}_4}{\displaystyle\text{Z}_3}+\text{V}}{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}\text{Z}_1}{\displaystyle\text{Z}_2}+\text{V}}=\frac{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\text{Z}_4}{\displaystyle\text{Z}_3}+1}{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\text{Z}_1}{\displaystyle\text{Z}_2}+1}\tag4
$$

Answer (score 0):

Remember that, in a resistive voltage divider, the grounded resistor is the one that goes in the numerator (on the other hand, in a capacitive divider, it is the series capacitor that goes in the numerator). It is trivial to prove this in the voltage divider formula.

If you keep that in mind, you can realize **you made a mistake in both of your voltage divider formulas**, as you wrote the series resistor in the numerator. It is the grounded one that goes there.